# Problem with installing Shark machine learning library

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I am Installing Shark machine learning library in my Laptop which its config is :

- CPU: CoreI7 10th generation
- GPU: Radeon RX640
- OS: Windows 10
- IDE: Visual studio 2019

according to shark website help, Boost library must be installed before any action .
I got the Boost library `boost_1_74_0-msvc-14.2-64` from [its boost website](https://www.boost.org/users/download/#repository). Running the exe makes a folder `C:\local\boost_1_74_0`

some helps from Youtube says it is enough to install boost and use the addresses belong to this folder and some other helps says you must build it , so I did two ways separately for two kind of installing.

After that , I got the shark library from [its official website](http://ml.org/sphinx_pages/build/html/rest_sources/installation.html#downloads)
or
http://image.diku.dk/shark/sphinx_pages/build/html/rest_sources/downloads/downloads.html

I started to extract it and put it in a source folder and then I made a build folder near it.
I run the CMAKE and put the source address in the source text box and build address in the build text box.
then I made to entries to CMAKE : `BOOST_ROOT:C:\local\boost_1_74_0` and `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR:C:\local\boost_1_74_0\lib64-msvc-14.2`
the I configured it , some messages were in the output page in the CMAKE:

> CMake Warning at C:/Program
> Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1179 (message):
> New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and
> imported   targets Call Stack (most recent call first):   C:/Program
> Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1303
> (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)   C:/Program
> Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1904
> (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)   Test/CMakeLists.txt:11 (find package)

I kept going it because it was just warning and I had put the BOOST address in the CMAKE config
so I generate it via CMAKE and the run the visual studio solution in ADMIN and build the shark.sln but the after a lot of compiling time , the result was : 198 projects FAILED

Visual studio makes these errors after building the shark project:

Error   LNK1181 cannot open input file '..\lib\Release\shark.lib'
Error   C2668   'shark::size': ambiguous call to overloaded function
Error   C3861   'make_iterator_range': identifier not found

these errors are repeated for 230 times in shark project building process

these errors makes me confused and I don't know what to do because when shark.lib is created that building process gets completed and in the middle of building , compiler is looking for what?

another item is shark::size error is not clear for me because all the relations between library files and header files in this project is clear but compiler cannot relate them together and makes error

Comment: By itself, the **warning** about "New Boost version may have..." is not a problem, so projects are failed due to other reasons. If you want us to help with those fails, then you need to provide more details about them (e.g. exact output). If you just want to resolve warnings, then you need either to update your CMake or downgrade Boost.

Comment: But when I build the project with visual studio 2019 , it fails the projects which they were congurated by cmake.I think that some items must be considered for building projects with vc142

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boost is a collection of libraries. Some must be built, others are header-only (just `#include`). Visual Studio is common enough that Boost provides a link to pre-built libraries. You downloaded the correct MSVC 14.2 build for VS2019.

Since Boost is a collection of libraries, sometimes library A needs library B. CMake knows about the dependencies in most Boost versions, but not the newest. So when a project tells CMake it needs Boost library A, CMake will automatically include B as well. If this is the problem with Shark, you'll need to manually add the missing Boost dependencies to `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: you are right but i the middle of building the project , why a lot of errors       ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 228 failed, 2 up-to-date, 10 skipped ==========

Comment: I search a lot about this error in the web and I think there are some items needed for installing shark: LAPACK(which needs INTEL fortran) , ATLAS and CBLAS libraries must be installed and then some compiler MACROs must be defined in the visual studio before starting to build, is there anyone who has the experience for installing shark on windows 10 and visual studio 2019?